# How to say "I have N years experience in ____."?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice

Is this correct,
私は**＿＿＿**で**N**年の経験があります。

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct even though 「私は」 is not needed in most cases.  Your reader/listener will know who you are talking about without using the pronoun.  English is a me-me-me language and Japanese is not.

Other natural-sounding sentence patterns would include:

・「[name of field] の分野{ぶんや}で N 年{ねん}の経験{けいけん}があります。」

・「[name of occupation] として N 年の経験があります。」

Comment: If he had to keep 「私」, could he use 「私には」 or perhaps 「私は～でＮ年間働いた経験を持っています」？